# Connect to MongoDB via SSH within R

Tags: r, mongodb, ssh

How can I create a SSH tunnel to a machine (RedHat Enterprise Linux) hosting a MongoDB (Version 3) and then run R scripts from my machine (windows) on the database?

I know how to connect to the machine via puTTY and then run an uploaded FCP transferred R script from the shell on the machine, however I want to perform the analysis from my PC so I can test my scripts quickly and export analyses and results easily.

Comment: If you have SSH access to the machine, it might be worthwhile to install RStudio Server so you have a development environment on metal. Especially if your mongodb is large.

Answer (score 3):

This is adapted from an instruction I have for our remote MySQL SSH connections. The remote database server is configured to listen to its local address on port 27017. (127.0.0.1:27017). You would want to replace 10.10.10.10 with the IP address of the MongoDB server.

```
1. Install putty.exe 
2. Start putty. 
3. Sessions Tab: 
  3a.   Set hostname like: 
  3b.   <username@hostname>
  3c.   Eg: mongo_user@mongodb.server.com
4. Connection : SSH : Tunnels tab.
  4a.   Source port: 27017
  4b.   Destination: 10.10.10.10:27017
5. Sessions Tab
  5a.   Saved Session: Type name such as “MongoDB Server”
  5b.   Select [Save] button
```

On your windows client, you would use a connection string to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (the local source port you configured in the putty connection above)

*edit to change 192.168.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 (wrong local/loopback address)*

Comment: How do I then connect to this via R?

Comment: Once you configure the putty tunnel, use it to login from the Windows client to the MongoDB server. On the Windows client, your R script will need to configure an ODBC connection. While I don't have a MongoDB set up to check, it looks like [rmongodb](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html) shoud do the trick. Your connection string would look something like `mongo <- mongo.create(host="127.0.0.1:27017",username="USER", passsword="XXX", db="database"`